# Convert Java Object to Json String to encrypt for Hmac authentication

Tags: java, json, hmac

Our partner is supporting HMAC authentication, where they send the hash when calling the api. On our side we compare the hash with the input sent. We are converting the input to json and then comparing it with the hash using apache commons HMACUtil.

```
public String calculateHmac(String data) {
    return new HmacUtils(HmacAlgorithms.HMAC_SHA_256, pass).hmacHex(data);
}

public boolean checkHmac(String data, String hmacHex) {
    return calculateHmac(data).equals(hmacHex);
}
```

However, when we convert into json, if we use

ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();

but if the partner converts  without using "withDefaultPrettyPrinter" then the hash does not match.

Is there a way not be dependent on each other on how we convert into json string?

Comment: You either need to agree on a standard, or you could simply check both for a matching hash?

Comment: Sorry, I did not get the last option, what do you mean by check both for a matching hash?

Comment: When you convert the json, you can convert it twice, one with pretty printing and one without the pretty printing and then check if either one matches, and accept it if it does? You could then toggle an internal flag based on which one matches so you know if you need pretty printing or not going forward.

Comment: What you want to do is a silly idea. You should definitely not call it JSON: You have created an entirely binary format: Some data is converted into some other binary representation, according to a precise spec. If you do the job exactly correct, byte for byte, the hashes will match. Otherwise, they will not. JSON fundamentally isn't binary, and JSON fundamentally has no features to say that e.g. injecting a space or newline someplace is forbidden, let alone where one should put the whitespace. In other words, 'hash up the result of JSONizing some data' serves no purpose, stop doing it.

Comment: That should work @sorifiend. Let me sleep on it

Comment: I get that and agree json isn't binary, do you have another approach to solving it? Is there another way to make sure both the partners meet a standard @rzwitserloot

Comment: Pick a binary format that has an exact specification, such as protobuf. You can work around it by defining an exact pretty printer behaviour for JSON, but this is very complicated and calling that 'JSON' would be highly misleading. I doubt you can avoid general misunderstanding, people see JSON and definitely aren't thinking "Oh, whitespace matters". Note that @sorifiend 's advice doesn't work; it's not 'pretty printed' and 'not pretty printed'. There are a billion pretty printing standards, you can't check them all.

Comment: yea, I saw there are different printing standards. Protobuf does ring some bell, but I don't have much expertise in it. Let me read more on it. Thanks

Comment: I am reading the http raw body before it gets converted to json using spring boot interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for client and server to not be dependent on each other as to how the server reconstructs the form of the message the client signed.

HMAC mechanisms depend on choosing a strict *Canonical Form* for the message, which both sides must follow. Client and server must construct the Canonical Form of the message in exactly the same way, for the HMACs to match.

> for HMAC to work reliably and prevent false errors (code mismatches) the JSON data must always be presented in some deterministic, also called normalised or canonical, order.

https://connect2id.com/blog/how-to-secure-json-objects-with-hmac